# Druid Spec to Truncate and Load in druid

Tags: druid

Could some please share me the sample spec to truncate and Load the data into druid.

I want to load the data into druid from csv file but the requirement is that the data should be truncate in the druid and then load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below command will work:

```
curl -k --noproxy "*" -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -H "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n <druid username>:<password> | base64)" -d '{ "interval" : "<start interval>/<end interval>" }' https://<hostname>:<portno.>/druid/coordinator/v1/datasources/<datsource name>/markUnused
```

or

```
curl -k --noproxy "*" -X 'DELETE' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' {<druid_ds_url>}/{<DatasourceName>}
```